# How to read form options element created through JavaScript looping

Tags: javascript

I have select age options form element and options for age are created using JavaScript looping and then I am trying read the value of option selected once the form is submitted. Console shows the value of selected option as a var I instead of actual value selected.

Here is code pen link to code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxLPpb?editors=1111

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Parag Patel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='container'>
    <label for="select">Select your age:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
          document.write('<option value="i">' + i + '</option>');
        }
      </script>
    </select>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var formInput = document.querySelector('#age');
    document.querySelector('#sub').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Age: ' + formInput.value);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What is `#sub` ?!!

Comment: `<option value="i">` you set it to `i`, a string and not the value of `i` variable

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. You were blocked from posting this question when you had only the codepen link in it. That happened because you are expected to provide an [mcve], instead of a link to an external site.

Answer (score 2):

You are not concatenating the *i* variable correctly in your value attribute.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  document.write ('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: it worked now...thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value "i" to your options. To insert a variable into the string just do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
   document.write ('<option value="'+i+'">' + i + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: It works now..ty